# replace dojo.query with Sizzle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, sizzle

Dojo has got the slowest selectors [compared to other JS frameworks](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-sizzle-vs-midori-vs-mootools-selectors-test/41).

I was wondering if it was possible to use Sizzle within Dojo to make dojo.query use it behind the scenes? I think it is used in jQuery that way, so it should be possible in Dojo too.

Couldn't find any info about how to do that.

PS
The test at the link seems to be being actively developed and changes daily, so make sure you select the latest version on that page.

**EDIT:** *it appeared that the numbers in the test were not correct, and the difference between Dojo and others is not really as radical. That makes the task of including Sizzle into Dojo not worth the effort.*

Comment: I'd still like to see it done -- in the process, have you found any tutorials on how to add sizzle into dojo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I question your numbers.  [Others](http://mootools.net/slickspeed/) have come to the opposite conclusion about Dojo's query engine.   They're all pretty fast, to the point where is probably doesn't make that big a difference.

Comment: well I'm not trusting there these numbers either but they are produced by running tests in your own browser online, so the only thing to question is the quality of tests themselves, I hope their sources are open

Comment: @Ken Franqueiro and snover fixed the test.  It was bogus and off by a factor of 100x iterating through indices rather than selectors -- dojo.query(0), dojo.query(1), etc.  See http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-sizzle-vs-midori-vs-mootools-selectors-test/41

Comment: great news! now Dojo is not _so_ far behind, but still it's much slower than jQuery

Comment: Much slower?  We went from the basis of this question, Dojo running about 20000% slower to it being maybe 23% slower in these particular benchmarks.  Enough to make a significant difference in most apps?  Maybe, but I wouldn't leap to that conclusion.  Dojo is more than just a query engine, and DOM queries are best handled by native calls on newer browsers anyway.

Comment: 50% is much slower to me, my test is the third one there (Firefox 7.0.1), however it's not that bad and Sizzle integration becomes not a very justified thing to do

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a precise answer to this, but it definitely seems possible.  According to a [dojo ticket](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/8547) this feature has been in the cards for quite a while.

The [dojo query documentation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/query) has a section called `Alternate Selector Engines` with a link to a [github repository](https://github.com/kriszyp/sizzle) which appears to have a fairly easy drop in replacement for the dojo query engine.

By performing a custom build of dojo, you can automatically bake in the sizzle engine. If you look at (the source distribution) `util/buildscripts/jslib/buildUtil.js` There is a parameter for `query`:

```
"query": {
        defaultValue: "default",
        helpText: "Select a DOM query engine. Default value is the normal dojo.query engine. Using query=sizzle will use the Sizzle engine."
            + "Normal Dojo tests are not run routinely with the Sizzle engine. See dojo/_base/sizzle.js for the version of Sizzle."
    },
```

Comment: I can't agree more - it does seem possible :) Dojo docs are funny - _Once installed, you can use the selector engine_ - but how do I install it? which Sizzle version is compatible with which Dojo? Couldn't find any info about that... hopefully someone who tried it himself will give more info.

Comment: Apparently there is an ominous query-sizzle.js file under dojo/_base. The plot thickens...

Comment: @missingno good find.  From looking at that file, it appears you can create a custom build of dojo that bakes in the sizzle engine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace dojo.query with sizzle.

You can say dojo.query, it should use sizzle.

In the dojo config

```
var dojoConfig = {
    selectorEngine: "sizzle",
    async: true
```

};

Use
https://github.com/kriszyp/sizzle
as you would do with any other dojo package

see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/query.html