# Using Sizzle in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo, sizzle, dojo-build

I've seen some questions ([replace dojo.query with Sizzle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063962/replace-dojo-query-with-sizzle)) regarding using Sizzle as a selector engine in dojo, and know it's possible, but can't seem to find any tutorials or information on how to go about it.

I know in your build.profile.js file, you can select a selector engine like so:

```
    selectorEngine: 'lite',
```

but how would I point to / replace 'lite' or 'acme' with sizzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Bower lover, I'd use bower to install sizzle `bower install sizzle`. In the profile you should set a falsy value to selectorEngine, to prevent loading any preexisting selector engine. To preload sizzle, add it to your build layer. Then set `selectorEngine: 'sizzle/sizzle'` in your dojoConfig (before loading Dojo on the page).

Comment: Awesome! I love bower too. Thanks :)

Comment: Given that sizzle is now AMD compatible, as noted, just specify sizzle for the selectorEngine param in your dojoConfig, and things should work.